# Visual studio не видит методов

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

Пишу лабу на C++. Visual Studio не видит оператора [] у класса вектор (и подсвечивает красным a[0][0]), а также не видит метода reserve(n) класса вектор. Решение уже пересобирал.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: `#include <vector>` ... Вот и все.

Comment: @Kotomi  выше оно есть (на скрине не поместилось)

Comment: А был бы текст, все бы поместилось... А не скриншот.

Comment: @Kotomi а текстом не показать красное подчеркивание